# How to use feathers-client and superagent in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, superagent, feathersjs

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as feathers from 'feathers-client';
import * as superagent from 'superagent';
// const superagent = require('superagent');
// const feathers = require('feathers/client');
// const rest = require('feathers-rest/client');
// import * as rest from 'feathers-rest/client';

const HOST = 'http://localhost:3030'; // Your base server URL here
const rest = feathers.rest(HOST);

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  private _app: any;
  constructor() {
    this._app = feathers() // Initialize feathers
      .configure(rest.superagent(superagent)); // Fire up rest
  }

  public test() {
      console.log('pepowopeoepeepw');
  }

}
```

I tried many things but keep getting error as

1. **src/client/app/services/api-service.ts(11,23): error TS2339: Property 'rest' does not exist on type 'typeof "**
2. **src/client/app/services/api-service.ts(18,17): error TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.**
3. **node_modules/feathers-client/index.d.ts(25,3): error TS7010: 'on', which lacks return-type annotation, implicitly has an 'any' return type.**

Not sure what is wrong?

Comment: Did you install feathers-client and superagent with npm? Are you using webpack or SystemJS?

Comment: yes I did install feathers-client and superagent with npm. Also I found the type definition for superagent so I installed that too.And I am using SystemJS

Comment: SystemJS can't detect npm packages automatically. You need to declare them in `systemjs.config.js`. Look at the 3rd-party libraries already declared in this file for inspiration (like rxjs) and add new "maps" for YOUR libraries.